# Cloudera strange process

Tags: java, process, terminal, cloudera-cdh, ps

I'm managing a cloudera cluster and I have a system process that consumes like 10GB of RAM. Checking it with ps -f it results in the command:

/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -cp /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0

I'm trying to figure out what this process does and if I could kill it, but I can't find anything relevant on the web. Anyone more expert than me can help me?

Thanks.

[SOLVED] the process was the Spark Job running, I don't know why it was taking like 10GB of virtual memory, but effectively it consumes just like 2GB

Comment: Can you paste all line?

Comment: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -cp /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/spark/conf/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-cdh5.5.1-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.5.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/spark/conf/yarn-conf/:/etc/hive/conf/:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/ST4-4.0.4.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/accumulo-core-1.6.0.jar

Comment: :/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/accumulo-fate-1.6.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/accumulo-start-1.6.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/accumulo-trace-1.6.0.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/ant-1.9.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/ant-launcher-1.9.1.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar

Comment: and continues..

Comment: Do you have installed spark on yarn ? Can you paste the output of "lsof -p pid"?

Comment: Yes there is Spark installed. I don't have lsof installed at the moment..

Comment: It can be a spark process, who is process owner?

Comment: The process owner is my account, but another person has launched this program. In fact we have a Spark workflow running that we launched with a spark submit. But on YARN consumes like 6GB of RAM, why it has 10GB of virtual memory assigned on the NN1?

Comment: Can you heapdump this process?